# Jquery Ajax call is incorrect being sent as GET Instead of POST

Tags: jquery

I am making a Cross Domain AJAX POST Call to my Rest WebService

This is my HTML Code

```
$(document).on("click", ".submit", function(e) {

 var name = $('#name').val();
var mobile = $('#mobile').val();
var email = $('#email').val();

 if(name==''||mobile==''||email=='')
 {
    alert('Please Fill All the Details');
return false;
 }
 else
 {
var information = {
    "name": name,
    "mobile": mobile,
    "email": email
}

var dataaa = JSON.stringify(information);

console.log(dataaa);

  $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
         url: 'http://192.168.2.46:8080/PostEx/test/testservice',
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: true,
            data: dataaa,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {

               alert(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        }); 

 }

});

<body>

<form method="POST">
<div class="required">
Name: <input class="required" type="text" id="name" name="name"> <span class="asterisk_input">  </span>   </br>
Phone: <input type="mobile" id="mobile" name="mobile"> <span class="asterisk_input">  </span>    </br>
E-mail: <input type="email" id="email" name="email"> <span class="asterisk_input">  </span>    </br>
</div>
  <input class="submit" type="submit">
</form>
</body>
```

I am observing under the Browser console

[image]

Sorry for the big image i don't know how to crop the picture .

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7605119/1059101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using JSONP you can't make a POST request.

A JSONP request doesn't use the XMLHTTPRequest object to do the request, it adds a `script` tag to the page that makes the request by loading the resource as Javascript. The `script` tag doesn't have a means of specifying the method of the request, it's always a GET request.